# Solving the equation relating to permutations $^{2n}P_3 =^{6}P_n$

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

[image]

How would you solve this equation?

So far i can only do 
LHS=
$^{2n}P_3=\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-3)!}=(2n)(2n-1)(2n-2)$ as I cancel out the $(2n-3)!$

For the RHS
I arrived at 
$^{6}P_n=\frac{(6)!}{(6-n)!}=\frac{720}{(6-n)!}$
But I don't know how to continue? 
As I can't seem to resolve $(6-n)!=(6-n)(5-n)(4-n)(3-n)$...?

The answer is n=3.

Please advise. Thank you and sorry in advance for any wrong formatting, tag labelling and title.

Comment: $n=3$ satisfies the permutation equation.

Comment: @diya, would you mind telling me how you did it? and the steps involved?

Comment: Big Hint : For $n \geq 7$ the number $(6-n)!$ doesn't  exist ...This means you only need to verify it for $n \leq 6$ which is easy .

Comment: @ComplexPhi, so do I just substitute numbers that are smaller than 7 in until I reach balance in both sides of the equation? Or are there other ways to do it?

Comment: Find the domain of definition first.LHS gives $2n\geq3$ and RHS gives $n\leq6$So $n$can be$=2,3,4,5,6$

Comment: I don't know if there are other ways but simply checking for the values of $n$ is a sure way to solve it .

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Note that:

$$\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-3)!}=\frac{(6)!}{(6-n)!}\implies\frac{(6-n)!}{(2n-3)!}=\frac{(6)!}{(2n)!}$$

---

Therefore, the following conditions must hold:

- $6\geq 2n$
- $6-n\geq0$
- $2n-3\geq0$

---

Note that:

- $6\geq 2n\implies n\leq3$
- $6-n\geq0\implies n\leq6$
- $2n-3\geq0\implies n\geq\frac32$

Therefore $2\leq n\leq3$.

---

So we only have two values of $n$ to test:

- $n=2\implies\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-3)!}=24\neq30=\frac{(6)!}{(6-n)!}$
- $n=3\implies\frac{(2n)!}{(2n-3)!}=120=\frac{(6)!}{(6-n)!}$

Hence the answer is $n=3$.